# tmux + iTerm2 + zsh - percent sign at the beginning of line

Tags: zsh, tmux, iterm

I work with tmux + iTerm2 integrated (`tmux -CC`). All works fine, besides that in zsh I get strange `%` at the beginning of line:

```
user@user] date
Fri Apr 11 03:12:39 PDT 2014
%
user@user]
```

I know that zsh signals with `%` that there is no `\n` at the end of line, but I am not sure what to do to get rid of it, or force tmux/iterm to use proper line endings

When I work with tmux + zsh and iterm *not integreated*, then I don't have the problem.

I tried (without success)

- `tmux -CC -u`
- `unset PROMPT_SP`

Comment: What is the content of `PS1`? It looks more like your prompt starts with a percent sign followed by a new line.

Comment: Check a similar question on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/645599/why-is-a-percent-sign-appearing-before-each-prompt-on-zsh-in-windows, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I use putty to log in to the remote server, which has tmux and zsh installed. Not only there was a `%` at the end of the line, but also lines were not separated correctly.

Assuming your user name is `ross`, and the remote server is `123.123.123.123`, you can log in again to solve the problem, i.e.

```
[ross@123.123.123.132]: ssh ross@123.123.123.123
[ross@123.123.123.132]:
```

I don't know why it solves the problem, but it works for me.